# SQLite3 attach Database performance

Tags: sqlite

I am working on a project that uses `SQLite` for handling `data aggregation`. I have `multiple SQLite database` files that are **split up by time**. I am planning on using the `SQLite ATTACH DATABASE` feature so I can run a single query against all the databases.

Each database has the same indexes and same table names. I wanted to be able to **run the single  query** that would pull records from all the databases and sum values and some basic stuff like that. Then **run an update** to **flag** those records as already processed.

The question is: Will `SQLite` parallel the the execution of these queries? Will it create one reader for each database? Will it know to skip some databases based on the query and the index that is there?

Comment: What is the conclusion of the story here? Is this still the case in 2023? can we query sqlite on multiple file db having the same Schema?

Answer (score 2):

SQLite does not do work in parallel.

Furthermore, if you have multiple tables with the same name, SQLite does not access all of them automatically; you would have to get data from each table separately and combine them by hand; something like this:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT SUM(x) FROM FirstDB.SomeTable   WHERE ...) +
       (SELECT SUM(x) FROM Second DB.SomeTable WHERE ...) +
       ...;
UPDATE FirstDB.SomeTable  SET Processed = 1 WHERE ...;
UPDATE SecondDB.SomeTable SET Processed = 1 WHERE ...;
...
```

Comment: So it sounds like the proxy idea may just be best. Send query calls out to different databases at the same time and then do some sort of merge sort.

Answer (score 2):

We used the sqlite in the exact same way you are going to do it. We have found no way of achieving what you want done.

In our case data was sorted according to time, so we simply queried all the databases and appended the ordered results to a list.

You can create a kind of proxy which would store the list of databases and handle all your queries. Unfortunately, each separate query will probably have to be manually joined, like in your `SUM()` case.

Comment: This is interesting it is a shame that they have not added that feature into the library bindings it could make sqlite a force to recon with if it supported that